# AJAX JQuery Deferred callbacks only get called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I am registering callbacks on a few jquery ajax objects.

So I have:

```
function main_getLogin( options ){
    g_userXHR = $.ajax({
        url:'ajx/_account.aspx',  
        type:'POST' ,cache:false, dataType:'json'
        })
        .success( function(data){
            //var loginData = data.ACCOUNT_INFO;
            //dlog(data);
    });

}
```

And a call back later - elsewhere

```
g_userXHR.success(function(d,status){
d = d.ACCOUNT_INFO;
if(d.NAME != "" && d.ERRORS.length == 0){//logged in

    $('#myRHpage .registeredUser').show();
    $('#myRHpage .unregisteredUser').hide();
    setupTabs();
}
else{//user is not logged in 

    $('#myRHpage .unregisteredUser').show();
    $('#myRHpage .registeredUser').hide();
}

});
```

This callback and all the others work perfectly the first time I am kicking off

```
main_getLogin();
```

the .success connected directly to g_userXHR gets called every-time, however the other callbacks attached outside of the function only gets fired the first time I call main_getLogin();

In addition, is there any way to declare a ajax object and send it later.
like g_userXHR.send();

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that code that's "elsewhere" does not re-add those "success" callbacks every time "main_getLogin()" is called, then they won't be run. Each call to "$.ajax" constructs a brand new "Deferred" object, so what you did to the first one won't affect the next such object jQuery builds for you.

If you want to *always* do certain things upon success, you can use "$.ajaxSuccess()":

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function() { ... });
```

Comment: What is an efficent way of readding these callbacks , or somehow having a global object.... I would love to simply say `g_userXHR.resend();`

Comment: After, some thought, and taking a look at ajaxSuccess, is there no other way? I have quite a few different ajax calls being made, and it would be a shame to have to wrap all my logic in $.ajaxSuccess - then if conditions to analyze what actually called it.

Comment: Well, if you have to do something special, then I don't see any alternative but to make sure that the code is called every time you start a new ajax request.

Comment: again thanks for your attention. Just to make sure however. There is no way to take a XHR object and simply resend it? seems so funny...

In addition, do you have any suggestions on how I can make sure that the deferred's are reattached. Right now all I can think of is a global function that would reattach them all...sloppy - but could be ok

**edit::**-another thought - I tried this earlier this morning and cant remember the snag I ran into ... could I use my own custom deferred functions as wrappers around the ajax calls. That way I can control when resolve and promise get handeled

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that, no; at least, not via the jQuery wrapper around it. I've never considered re-using an XHR object because they're so easy to create. Yes, I would wrap the additional handler setup in a function somewhere.